# How can I set parameters in an external table?

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

I'm tring to create an external table from a csv file with SQL. 
The csv file has this structure:

```
I001234
I012344
I000234
...
```

I wrote this code for the upload:

```
create table Arranger_check(
matriid char(8))
organization external (
type oracle_loader default directory ext_tab_data access parameters
(
records delimited by newline 
)
location('file.csv')) reject limit unlimited;
```

If I try to interrogate db, the result is wrong. I have eight digits and the last is space 32(ascii). The result is that a query with IN or NOT IN doesn't work.

```
matriid
--------
I001234
I012344
I000234
...
```

I've tried to change matriid char(8) in char(7), but create table uploads 0 rows.

Comment: Why are you using `char` instead of `varchar2`?

Comment: i've tried with varchar2 and result is the same

Comment: If you still have the trailing space in the `varchar2(8)` column then it sounds like your file has trailing spaces; so you want to trim those off, presumably?

Comment: i've check my csv file and after deleted all space, when i create table sql it adds trailing space

Comment: Obviously, if you store `'I001234'` in a `char(8)` column then it has to become `'I001234 '`, so that's one issue. If the source data has trailing spaces that need trimming then SQL\*Loader can do that, but storing it as `char8)` will add spaces again.

Comment: After you've deleted the spaces, are you creating it with `varchar2` or still with `char`? A `char(8)` value will always be padded back to 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your column as `char(8)` then it will always be padded with spaces, whether the value in the file has spaces or not: if I make the file have a mix:

```
create table Arranger_check(
matriid char2(8))
...

select matriid, length(matriid), dump(matriid) as dumped
from Arranger_check;

MATRIID  LENGTH(MATRIID) DUMPED                                  
-------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
I001234                8 Typ=96 Len=8: 73,48,48,49,50,51,52,32   
I012344                8 Typ=96 Len=8: 73,48,49,50,51,52,52,32   
I000234                8 Typ=96 Len=8: 73,48,48,48,50,51,52,32
```

With `varchar2` the column value will only have spaces if the file has trailing spaces, so with the same file with a mix you get varying lengths in the table:

```
create table Arranger_check(
matriid varchar2(8))
...

select matriid, length(matriid), dump(matriid) as dumped
from Arranger_check;

MATRIID  LENGTH(MATRIID) DUMPED                                  
-------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
I001234                8 Typ=1 Len=8: 73,48,48,49,50,51,52,32    
I012344                7 Typ=1 Len=7: 73,48,49,50,51,52,52       
I000234                7 Typ=1 Len=7: 73,48,48,48,50,51,52
```

If you want the column values to not have trailing spaces even if the file values do, you need to trim them off if they exist:

```
create table Arranger_check(
matriid varchar2(8))
organization external (
type oracle_loader default directory ext_tab_data access parameters
(
  records delimited by newline
  fields
  (
    matriid char(8) rtrim
  )
)
location('file.csv')) reject limit unlimited;
```

Then with the same file with a mix of values with and without spaces:

```
select matriid, length(matriid), dump(matriid) as dumped
from Arranger_check;

MATRIID  LENGTH(MATRIID) DUMPED                                  
-------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
I001234                7 Typ=1 Len=7: 73,48,48,49,50,51,52       
I012344                7 Typ=1 Len=7: 73,48,49,50,51,52,52       
I000234                7 Typ=1 Len=7: 73,48,48,48,50,51,52
```

Note that `rtrim` will have no real effect if you stick with `char(8)`, as it's that data type that causes all the values to be re-padded with spaces to the full size of the column. You need to use `varchar2(8)`.

Comment: ok ,thanks a lot for your answer, but why use cgar in the fields ?

Comment: Because the [SQL\*Loader data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-1C9801B0-4807-438F-81C8-6746827DD0D8) are different to the Db data types.